# Cognos Report Studio Crosstab drill thru

Tags: cognos, cognos-10, cognos-bi

I have a Crosstab report (10.2.2) which has 4 sub-reports that when you drill-through each report. I have drill-through on the row (TOS Level1) and would like to do that to the columns for (Emp Level 2 & 3). However when i go from prompt pages the Emp level works until i click on the TOS Level1. Then i get back all the Emp level data which if i only selected 1 value in prompt page i only want to see that 1 value i selected in prompt page not all the Emp Level data.

Report 1 and sub-reports are similar in layout. The sub-reports only add 1 column for the TOS level as you go down. TOS levels 1-5 for columns in rows for report. I can then drill back up by clicking next column in that row.

Report layout: 
            columns
Revenue    | Emp Level2 |
           | Current period  | prior period  | Difference %  |Contrib to Trend %
Rows
(TOS Level1) 
Ancillary
Facility
Inpatient
Outpatient
Services
Other

The 3 prompt pages are for Emp Level 1, Emp Levels 2 & 3 (same prompt page, both optional), TOS Level1

When i choose TOS levels it works fine for First report page. I have the correct TOS items and Emp levels present. When i click on 1 of the TOS rows i get all the Emp level data even though i chose only 1 group to show in first report. How can i get the Emp levels to show properly when i click on the TOS row item?

Thanks for the help. hope i explained this well enough.

Thanks VBnewbie

Comment: Can you try and generalize your question? You have thrown a lot of specific jargon that is tough to follow since we are not familiar with your data domain or use case. Most problems can be reduced down to a much simpler example and will result in a greater likelihood of someone answering your question.

Comment: I have 1 main report and 4 sub-reports. each sub-report has only an extra column in the TOS area. This is for the users who want to see where they are drilling deeper in report. Problem i am having is that i cannot get the report to drill correctly through the reports when i select the TOS level. it wont drill through the reports. Does that help?